# Appserv, Xampp, Wampserver / Phpmyadmin HTTP Errors

Tags: php, mysql, http, phpmyadmin

I opened a webpage on internet and I wanted to add a memberships system with a database to keep important informations for my and my customers' safety.

To create a memberships system, as far as I learned, it is necessary to have mysql app installed on the computer and phpmyadmin.

As a Win10 User, I've opened Internet Information Services, I can reach to 127.0.0.1 and localhost. In 127.0.0.1 and localhost, there is a blue Windows Internet Information Services screen.

I installed Xampp for phpmyadmin.

When I enter things like 127.0.0.1/Xfolder to the address bar, I can see everything inside the X folder, but when I enter 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin to the address bar, I can't see anything but annoying http errors.

I thought that there might be a problem with the Xampp I downloaded and I tested a different Xampp, AppServ, Wampserver etc. Again, I came across with HTTP errors with different codes likes HTTP ERROR 404, 404.3 404.17, 500, 500.19...)

Current error example:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module: IIS Web Core
Notification: BeginRequest
Handler: Not yet determined
Error Code: 0x80070003
Configuration Error: Unable to read configuration file
Configuration File: \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpmyadmin\web.config
Requested URL: http://localhost:80/phpmyadmin/
Physical Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpmyadmin\
Login Method: Not yet determined
Login User: Not yet determined

Configuration Source:
    -1:
     0:

More information:
This error occurs when the Web server or Web application has a problem reading the configuration file. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what is causing this error.
Show more info »
```

What may cause this problem?
How can I reach to myphpadmin?

Thanks from now on to everyone who will try to help.

Comment: So you're running Apache _and_ IIS? You don't need full Xampp to run phpMyAdmin necessarily, you can host it on IIS if you've installed PHP into IIS. Or it might be simpler to switch off IIS and just use the Apache instance with comes with your Xampp installation.

Comment: Whether I run or not run Apache or IIS, I come across with a HTTP problem. Now I've copied phpmyadmin folder into the xampp folder and copied the xampp folder into the C:\inetpub\wwwroot folder. What I get now is an explanation like Server Error in Application '/'. It says Access Denied, you do not have permissions to view this directory, ask the administrator of the web server to grant you access to 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xampp\phpmyadmin'. etc,

Comment: Well then you need to grant access. Remember that IIS processes run as a different user than you personally do.

Comment: Really though, I'd recommend just uninstalling IIS, and then deleting and re-installing XAMPP, and using that as it's intended. More likely to be successful than trying to work around IIS being there.